# How to add a select to theme options

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im setting up a custom template, working on options for the admin and i would like to add  a  combobox to pick up a category. 
Something like: 
Editor's Pick Category: []

I already know how to add options to the panel, but not something like a category that comes from wordpress itself.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a select option with pre populated fields you would first grab all of the categories from your blog then store it in an array.

```
// Grabs Categories from Wordpress
$tt_categories = array();  
$tt_categories_obj = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
foreach ($tt_categories_obj as $tt_cat) {
$tt_categories[$tt_cat->cat_ID] = $tt_cat->cat_name;}
$categories_tmp = array_unshift($tt_categories, "Select a category:");
```

Then you would call it like so in your theme options

```
//shows a select box in theme options page
$options[] = array( "name" => __('Wordpress Category','framework_localize'),
        "desc" => __('Select a category','framework_localize'),
        "id" => "wp_category",
        "std" => "1",
        "type" => "select",
        "options" => $tt_categories);
```